# Proxy to SSL Endpoint with webpack-dev-server proxy

Tags: vue.js, http, ssl, https, proxy

I am trying to do an axios GET request in vue3:

***vue.config.js***

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'https://example-url.com/',
  }
})
```

***Request.js***

```
const url = "http://localhost:8080/example/.../"
```

When sending the request I am getting the following error:
***400 (Bad Request)***

The origin of the ***400 (Bad Request)*** is a missing SSL certificate, which I am getting asked for in the browser when accessing `https://example-url.com/example/.../` without the proxy (results in CORS policy error).

Why am I not getting asked for a client certificate when accessing the api via the proxy?

How can I configure my request that I am getting asked for a client certificate?

Comment: You can set `rejectUnauthorized` to `false` in the Axios options

Comment: @Lissy93 rejectUnauthorized to false in options => axios(options) is not solving my problem. I saw some people providing a httpsAgent in the axios request. 
But since I am only having a frontend i can not use 'fs' and 'https' in my request.js

Comment: did you check the docs? https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy and https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration

Comment: @jasie i checked the docs but theres nothing about http to https connection or ssl certificates.

The proxy is working. But the server is not asking for a client certificate when accessing it via the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for appending SSL Certifcate in webPack devServer Proxy

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
transpileDependencies: true,
devServer:{
proxy: {
  '^/api': {
    target: {
      protocol: "https:",
      host: "base-url",   
      port: 443,
      pfx: fs.readFileSync('pfxFile.pfx'),
      passphrase: 'your-passphrase',     
    },
    changeOrigin: true,
   }
  }
 }
})
```

Request URL then needs to go to e.g. http://localhost:8080/api